# How to get classes from different namespaces

Tags: visual-studio

In one class I have a library project with a file class1 
with namespace : solution.Class1

and i have another class library project in the same solution with a file class2 
with namespace : solution.Class2

How i get objects from solution.Class1 namespace in class2 file ?
It is not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the project 1 from project 2.  Right click on project 2 and you should see the dialog option.